# SQL to calculate values based on applicable formula and return result to related column

Tags: sql-server, query

I have a table with various items and their sale

```
    itemNumbers  | TotalSales |
=================|============|
        A              100
        B              50
        C              30
        D              70
        etc.           etc.
```

My items are subject to various taxes (*please note that this one is not a SQL table*):

```
Items   | TaxRate(%)
========|========
A           5
B           8
C           8
D           5
```

I'd like to calculate appropriate taxes accordingly and return results to related column:

```
    itemNumbers  | TotalSales | %5 Tax Collected | %8 Tax Collected
=================|============|====================================
        A              100             5                0
        B              50              0                4
        C              30              0                2.4
        D              70              3.5              0
        etc.           etc.
```

How could this be done?

Comment: Where does the tax rate table/mapping live?

Comment: because this is a special situation these rates are not to be used from the database. These are only a few items, and I just know which rate applies to which one.

Comment: Then hand type them into a #Temp table and join to it... or just hard code it. Would this not work?

Comment: @Datazita - are there a fixed number of tax rates?  (5%, 8%)?

Comment: Yes. @ScottHodgin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CASE` expressions

```
--demo setup
drop table if exists table1
go
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  itemNumbers VARCHAR(1),
  TotalSales INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO Table1
  (itemNumbers, TotalSales)
VALUES
  ('A', '100'),
  ('B', '50'),
  ('C', '30'),
  ('D', '70');

--solution
SELECT itemnumbers
    ,TotalSales
    ,CASE 
        WHEN itemnumbers IN ('A','D')
            THEN totalsales * .05
        ELSE 0
        END AS '%5 Tax Collected'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN itemnumbers IN ('B','C')
            THEN totalsales * .08
        ELSE 0
        END AS '%8 Tax Collected'
FROM TABLE1
```

---

```
| itemnumbers | TotalSales | %5 Tax Collected | %8 Tax Collected |
|-------------|------------|------------------|------------------|
| A           | 100        | 5.00             | 0.00             |
| B           | 50         | 0.00             | 4.00             |
| C           | 30         | 0.00             | 2.40             |
| D           | 70         | 3.50             | 0.00             |
```